# Backbone.js - Simple CORS echo server

Tags: node.js, rest, backbone.js, cors

I'm trying to learn Backbone.js and thus follow tutorials.

In particular, I'm following a tutorial by [Thomas David](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsEw2i4wQMM) (founder of Backbone Tutorials).

The problem is that the basic server he gives on his [GitHub](https://github.com/thomasdavis/video-backbone-beginner-server) doesn't work.

So my question is the following :

- Does anyone have a bare-bone Node.js CORS-enabled echo server that could work with Backbone.js ?

I only want the server to be able to answer certain requests with JSON strings (like a REST server) so that I can concentrate on learning Backbone.js.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: [You seem to be mired in the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try asking a specific question about a specific problem. Obviously, you have some sort of Node.js CORS solution that you've tried, but you haven't posted the code here for us to see what's wrong. You haven't shown code that is calling it. You haven't stated the domains of the source and destination. You haven't stated if either (or both) are on SSL. Cheers : )

Comment: I actually asked the specific question just a day or two before I asked this one, but nobody was able to answer it ... :S

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an echo-server in node.js specifically for issues like this: https://github.com/monsur/echo-server. Check the "samples" directory for an example of how to test CORS requests.

Comment: Ok, so I looked at the code but the server doesn't seem to work either ... :S I don't want to serve files, I want to respind to backbone's ajax requests with JSON strings.